# Clickhouse query takes long time to execute with array joins and group by

Tags: performance, clickhouse

I have a table student which has over 90 million records. The create table query is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student(
id integer,
student_id FixedString(15) NOT NULL,
teacher_array Nested(
teacher_id String,
teacher_name String,
teacher_role_id smallint
),
subject_array Nested(
subject_id String,
subject_name String,
subject_category_id smallint
),
year integer NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=MergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY id
PARTITION BY year
ORDER BY id
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

The following query takes 5 seconds to execute:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct id) as student_count,
(
SELECT count(distinct id)
FROM student
ARRAY JOIN teacher_array
WHERE hasAny(subject_array.subject_category_id, [1, 2]) AND (teacher_array.teacher_role_id NOT IN (1))
) AS total_student_count,
count(*) OVER () AS total_result_count,
teacher_array.teacher_role_id AS teacher_id
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM student
ARRAY JOIN subject_array
)
ARRAY JOIN teacher_array
WHERE (subject_array.subject_category_id IN (1, 2)) AND (teacher_array.teacher_role_id NOT IN (1))
GROUP BY teacher_array.teacher_role_id
ORDER BY student_count DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Expecting the query to run within 500 milliseconds is there any workaround for this? Tried using **uniq** and **groupBitmap** still the execution time comes around 2 seconds.